# Is there an easier way to write this without putting it in a function?

Tags: syntax, lua

I do this nearly every line:

```
if printAll then print("message for debugging") end
```

Is there a way to *syntax sugar* this, **without** putting it in a function?

```
local function cPrint(text)  --conditional printing
  if printAll then
    print(text)
  end
end

cPrint("message for debugging")
```

Because that function would have to constantly pass a variable only to find out that it isn't needed. Since `printAll` is usually false, this kind of misuse of resources is not what I want. This function might get run millions of times per minute, it just feels bad to pass an argument that uses memory only to be discarded.

So is there a way to discard this condition before an argument is passed that's a little nicer to look at? (The main reason being that it's more confusing to read nested if-else structures with those lines in there that start with "if".)

Comment: As I understand your question, I don't see any way to write `if printAll then print("message for debugging") end` in a more simple way (while keeping the readability ok)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
local cPrint
if printAll then
   cPrint=print
else
   cPrint=function()end
end
```

It saves executing the `if`, but not the function call.

Here is an alternative, that executes a hidden `if`, but avoids the function call:

```
_= printAll and print("message for debugging")
```

It's not really any more readable than

```
if printAll then print("message for debugging") end
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one would still save the string as a local variable, pass it to the function as an argument to find out that it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: Why is it:
`if printAll then
 cPrint=print`
and not
`if printAll then
 cPrint=print()`? I.e. with parenthesis after the print, since it's a function.